# How to make a templated class a friend of another templated class

Tags: c++, templates, friend

For educational purposes I'm writing a templated Stack class based on a singly linked list. I have written a class for a node:

```
template <typename T>
class StackNode {
    private:
        T data;
        StackNode<T> *next;
        // TODO: make Stack a friend
};
```

and I started writing the stack itself:

```
template <typename T>
class Stack {
    private:
        StackNode<T> *head;
        unsigned long long int size;
    public:
        Stack(): head(nullptr), size(0) {}
        void push(const T& element) {
            StackNode<T> *new_element = new StackNode<T>;
            new_element -> data = element;
            new_element -> next = head;
            head = new_element;
            ++size;
        }
};
```

Obviously, these two lines

```
            new_element -> data = element;
            new_element -> next = head;
```

are giving me trouble, because I'm trying to get access to private members. I want to make `Stack` a friend of `StackNode`. How can I do that?

When I write `friend class Stack<T>` in my TODO line in the `StackNode`, my CLion IDE underlines `Stack` with a red squiggly line and it says that I have redefinition of `Stack` as a different kind of symbol. I don't know how to fix that.

UPD:
my `main` function looks like this:

```
int main() {
    Stack<long long int> s;
    s.push(12);
    return 0;
}
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Why not define the class StackNode as struct in the private scope of Stack? Then you won't have that issue. No need for private member in StackNode then, because it is not visible to the outside anway.

Comment: Furthermore you should show a minimal reproduceable example, since this won't work without forward declarations anyway. So we cannot be sure what you are doing wrong.

Comment: @lars Again, for educational purposes I don't want to define StackNode as a struct.

Comment: @lars I added my main function. Now it's the full script.

Comment: For educational purpose it makes sense to choose a simple, good design. I think this not good "friend" example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your issue is still not reproducible / complete.
If you want to such an issue to be solved, try an online compiler like wandbox.
 An example is complete, if you can copy paste it into an online compiler and it leads to the error, that you want to be solved.

We can only guess what your issue is. Maybe you missed the forward decl. This way a friend declaration is done with the same class dependency structure as in your example:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class Foo;

template<class T>
class Bar
{
public:
    Bar(T t) : v(t) {}

private:
    T v;
    friend class Foo<T>;
};

template<class T>
class Foo
{
public:
    void Fun(Bar<T> bar)
    {
        std::cout << bar.v;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Bar<int> bar(99);
    Foo<int> foo;
    foo.Fun(bar);
}
```

Comment: Surprisingly that helped. I forgot to declare the class before declaring it a friend.